# creating a hyperlink in django using href

Tags: python, html, django

I tried to copy the way this django tutorial did their hyperlinks for my own project: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/.

However, on my screen, I do not have hyperlinks, just regular text. What I currently have in my index is a bunch of names of units, and I want the user to be able to click on that unit to get a more detailed view of that unit's information. This is what I currently have in my templates, views, and urls:

urls:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'calc'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.UnitView.as_view(), name='unit'),
]
```

views:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from .models import Unit, Class

# Create your views here.

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'calc/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'unit_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Unit.objects.all()

class UnitView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Unit
    template_name = 'calc/unit.html'
```

index.html:

```
{% if unit_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for unit in unit_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'calc:unit' unit.id %}"></a>{{ unit.unit_name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No units are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

unit.html:

```
{{unit.unit_class}}
```

My guess is that either I'm using href incorrectly, or my urls.py is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `{{ unit.unit_name }}` **inside** the `<a>` tag

The contents of an `<a>` tag are what get rendered as the link

```
<a href="{% url 'calc:unit' unit.id %}">{{ unit.unit_name }}</a>
```

Comment: this must be the html equivalent of the missing parenthesis that I can never find for 5 hours and need to show 10 different people before somebody actually finds it. thanks for spotting that.